# Finding the frequency of each unique value of an attribute in a relation (RELATIONAL ALGEBRA)

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra

I am trying to figure out how I can use aggregate functions to solve this problem. For example if I had the table

enrolled(student-id, course-id)
123 897
123 645
589 452
009 897

If I wanted to find the number of courses each student is enrolled in, how would I go about doing that? I was thinking of using the `count` function but I don't know how to separate each student-id

Comment: You could use the `group by` operator.

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give definitions & a reference (textbook name, edition & page).

Answer (score 0):

In SQL: Use the GROUP BY and COUNT operators.